# Disable jconsole popup: "Secure connection failed. Retry insecurely?"

Tags: java, jconsole

Is there a way to disable this jconsole popup?

[image: jconsole "Secure connection failed. Retry insecurely?"]

I know I can set up SSL per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdemv, but that would mean I'd need to do that on all servers (java) and all clients (jconsole). Not the most friendly solution for non-critical in-house apps. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible. Jconsole always tries first to connect using SSL and it's impossible to alter this behavior. From jconsole sources it's determined by

```
 private boolean shouldUseSSL = true;
```

which can be set to false only after it fails to connect using SSL.
Suggestions: use other JMX client tool (say jvisualvm or jmc) or  enable SSL.

Comment: Zulu Mission Control also works nicely as JMX client

Answer (score 1):

Not using SSL is possible! Use `jconsole -debug -J"-Djava.util.logging.config.file=FILENAME"` to see the logged exception. Probably you also need to configure the parameter `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=server.example`